# Tuning multiple losses in a multi-headed neural network

Tags: pytorch, neural-network

I have a network to simultaneously predict a max, and a min, using the same logits (an impossible task, but hear me out). Basically, I want to turn a knob to say "now predict the max of a given set of values" or to predict the min. If the knob is in between, it 'll predict a min or max with 50% probability. My code is based on the You Only Train Once paper: https://openreview.net/pdf?id=HyxY6JHKwr. The paper claims that you can train one network, and then tune how you combine the losses, to produce the network you want. So in my case, I want to tune it in such a way that my network either predicts the max of a given set of numbers, or the min. But I am failing at this task. My network model is as follows

```
class MyModel(Module):
def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_dim):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.input_dim = input_dim
    self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
    self.emb = Embedding(num_embeddings = vocab_size, embedding_dim = embedding_dim)
    self.l1 = Linear(input_dim * embedding_dim, 64)
    self.l2 = Linear(64, 32)
    self.l3 = Linear(32,10)
    
    self.loss_parameter_mlp = Sequential(
        Linear(2, 2),
        Sigmoid(),
    )

def forward(self, x, lambd):
    lambd = self.loss_parameter_mlp(lambd)
    x = self.emb(x).reshape(-1, self.input_dim * self.embedding_dim)
    x = ReLU()(self.l1(x))
    x = x * lambd[:,0].reshape(-1, 1) + lambd[:,1].reshape(-1,1)
    x = ReLU()(self.l2(x))
    x = x * lambd[:,0].reshape(-1, 1) + lambd[:,1].reshape(-1,1)
    logits = ReLU()(self.l3(x))
    return logits
```

My inputs are 10 integers from 1 to 99, and my model outputs are the logits - the argmax of which should contain either the min, or the max, based on my hyperparameters lambd. I specifically chose this problem, since I want the network to predict two polar opposites (max and min) at the same time, which it cannot. It's (in my mind) a simpler version of the problem the paper is trying to solve. My training code is as shown below

```
# Training
epochs = 200

alpha = np.linspace(0, 1, epochs)
np.random.shuffle(alpha)
np.linspace(1, 0, int(epochs/2))))
for epoch in range(epochs):
    
    lambd = torch.tensor([[alpha[epoch], (1 - alpha[epoch])]], dtype=torch.float32)
        
    for batch, x in enumerate(train_loader):
        y_max = torch.argmax(x, axis=1)
        y_min = torch.argmin(x, axis=1)
        lambd_b = lambd.expand(len(y_max), -1)
        y_pred = model(x, lambd_b)
        loss_max = CE_loss(y_pred, y_max)
        loss_min = CE_loss(y_pred, y_min)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = alpha[epoch] * loss_max + (1 - alpha[epoch]) * loss_min
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

However, the network learns to ignore the parameters lambd (in other words, the knobs to tune max or min just doesn't work). The network does learn to predict max and min (they share the same accuracy) - which is expected. What should I do to ensure that the knobs work?